# Complex number in binomic form

Tags: linear-algebra

$$(1-i)^6 \cdot \{(\sqrt3 + i)^3\}$$ to be written in the $a+bi$ form 
this is a linear algebra problem. I need to find the $a+bi$ format of the question.

Comment: hold up the square root is just on 3

Comment: OK. What have you tried? Many ways to solve this.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to calculate the square root of $3+i$ ... miles easier like that !

Comment: The obvious thing here is just to expand everything and collect the real and imaginary parts. Where in that process are you getting stuck?

Comment: so i got (8e^-3pi/2)(8e^pi/2) how do i convert to a+bi form from here?

Comment: @robertlikessaif why did you convert to exponential/polar form???? You csn just expand the powers using binomial theorem. No need for exponential at all.

Comment: $(1-i)/\sqrt{2}$ is an eigth root of unity & $(\sqrt{3}+i)/2$ is a twelth root of unity ... should be easy from there ?

Comment: Just expand:  $-64$

Answer (score 2):

$$a = (1-i)^6 = \left(\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4}\right)^6 = 8e^{-i3\pi/2} = 8i$$

$$b = (\sqrt{3}+i)^3 = \left(2e^{i\pi/6}\right)^3 = 8e^{i\pi/2} = 8i$$

$$ab = -64$$

Comment: Best answer as this is shows exactly the reason for swapping to exponential form.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+i)^6=(-2i)^3=8i$.

$(\sqrt3+i)^3=8(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i)^3=8i$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-i)^6=1-6i+15i^2-20i^3+15i^4-6i^5+i^6=1-6i-15+20i+15-6i-1=8i$$
$$(\sqrt{3}+i)^3=\sqrt{3}^3+3\sqrt{3}^2i+3\sqrt{3}i^2+i^3=3\sqrt{3}+9i-3\sqrt{3}-i=8i$$
so expression is $-64$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:** Simplify $$(1-i)^6\cdot\sqrt{(3+i)^3}\tag1$$

---

Let's start with $(1-i)^6$ first. Observe that $(1-i)^2=-2i$. Therefore,$$(1-i)^6=\{\color{blue}{(1-i)^2}\}^3=(\color{blue}{-2i})^3=8i\tag2$$

---

Now, focus on $\sqrt{(3+i)^3}$. We can simplify that into $(3+i)\sqrt{3+i}$. To simplify the square root, assume$$\sqrt{3+i}=a+bi\implies 3+i=a^2-b^2+2abi\tag3$$
Solving the system$$a^2-b^2=3$$$$ab=\dfrac 12$$
Gives two different values of $a,b$. Next, multiply them against $8i$ to get the answer.